# problemas al iniciar apache y mysql en XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xmpp

Cuando instalo XAMPP me da el siguiente error:

> [Apache]  Apache Service detected with wrong path 1:04:20 PM  [Apache]
>     Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or 1:04:20 PM 
>   [Apache]  Uninstall/disable the other service manually first 1:04:20
>   PM  [Apache]  Found Path: "C:\xampp-old\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k
>   runservice 1:04:20 PM  [Apache]   Expected Path:
>   "d:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice 1:04:20 PM  [mysql]
>     MySQL Service detected with wrong path 1:04:20 PM  [mysql]  Change
>   XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or 1:04:20 PM  [mysql]
>     Uninstall/disable the other service manually first 1:04:20 PM 
>   [mysql]   Found Path: C:\xampp-old\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe
>   --defaults-file=c:\xampp-old\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql 1:04:20 PM  [mysql]   Expected Path: d:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe
>   --defaults-file=d:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql

y cuando trato de iniciar apache y mysql se queda pensando asi:

> 1:08:01 PM  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache service... 1:08:02 PM
>   [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL service...

He buscado y he buscado y no doy con la solucion he cambiado los puertos tambien y nada de nada, si me pudieran ayudar; gracias.

Comment: Este post puede ayudarle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547759/apache-service-detected-with-wrong-path

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que haya otro servidor web en ejecución y eso esté ocupando el puerto.

Mira a ver si es el de Windows, aquí tienes unas [instrucciones](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/324090/how-to-start-and-stop-individual-web-sites-in-iis) de Microsoft para hacerlo.